# Getting count byjoining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
1)question  
2)options
3)answers
```

Table 1 contains list of multiple choice questions. Table 2 contains multiple choices for the question.

Consider an example, I have the question "Which game do you like most?"

It is stored in table 1 with id 1. For this question there are 3 choices in table 2; as "cricket", "football", "tennis" with ids 1,2 & 3.

When a user answer this question the question id, and option id are stored to the third table as if he select football, entry in table 3 is question id and option id.

If another user select same option new entry is stored in table 3.

My need is that I want to get the count of each options in table 3.

Consider 10 users select cricket, 15 users select football, no user select tennis, so I need count as 10,15,0 with its corresponding option id

Table name: questions

```
--------------------------------
| id |      question            |
--------------------------------
|  1 | which game u like most   |
```

---

Table Name: options

```
------------------------------------------------
| id |  qid  |         option_name               |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   1   |          cricket                   |
------------------------------------------------
| 2  |   1   |          football                  |
------------------------------------------------
| 3  |   1   |          tennis                    |
------------------------------------------------
```

Table Name: answers

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | qid | optionId                       |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 3                              |
---------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1   | 3                               |
----------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1   | 2                               |
----------------------------------------------
```

The above table means that, 2 people choose tennis, 1 people choose football and no one choose cricket. So I need result table as

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id | question                | option_name | count |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | which game u like most  | cricket     |   0   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | which game u like most  | football    |   1   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | which game u like most  | tennis      |   2    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I tried, I didnt get the count for cricket, because no one selected cricket.I must get count of cricket as 0. Can any one help me solve the issue?
My sql code is

```
SELECT count(an.optionId) count , op.option_name, q.question from
questions q, options op, answers an where q.id=1
and  q.id=op.qid
and op.id=an.optionId
group by q.question, op.option_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()` :

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(an.optionId),0) as count , op.option_name, q.question from
questions q
INNER JOIN options op
 ON(q.id=op.qid )
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers an 
 ON(p.id=an.optionId) 
where q.id=1
group by q.question, op.option_name
```

Please avoid the use of implicit join syntax(comma separated ) and use only the correct syntax of a join! `LEFT JOIN` with implicit syntax getting more hard to read and more easy to make mistakjes.

Comment: Working fine. I am new to sql, so I spend a lot of time in this query. Thanks